# Moving from visual studio to java IDE

Tags: java, .net, netbeans

I migrate from c# to Java. I work on some java tutorial using NetBeans IDE.
In visual studio solution divided to projects according to 
developers needs.For example, I use Data project to works dataBase or 
Models project that contains my entities.

As I understand what is called solution in visual studio in java IDE called Project.
If in visual studio I can create project that is part of
solution where is entities stored what is considered a good practice
Where should i keep entities in in java IDE?

Comment: What do you mean by "entities"?   Are you talking about design diagrams?  Different (Java) IDEs provide support for modeling diagrams, typically as plugins.   For example: https://netbeans.org/features/uml/

Comment: @StephenC, In .NET land, Models are usually the view model or DTOs, and Entities are used to refer to your business/domain objects. It's not uncommon to create separate projects in a .NET solution to separate this out.  So you may have three or more projects to represent the web layer, the services layer, and the data-access layer.

Answer (score 0):

In a number of Java IDEs, the analogue to solutions is usually called a workspace. Depending on the IDE, a project may be called a module or a project. You can add multiple projects to a workspace and achieve a separation similar to what you had in .NET that way.

However, as you're making the switch from C# to Java, I'd recommend just going with a single project as you're ramping up so you don't have to worry about the idiosyncrasies that occur with multi-module stuff.  Focus on learning the syntax, idioms, and pattern differences first and then go after the project organization.

Another thing that's usually different, especially if you're using Maven.  In Java, your unit tests typically live in the same project as your actual code, with a directory structure like:

```
./src/main/java
./src/test/java
```

Comment: The OP specifically referred to NetBeans which does not use workspaces.

Comment: Doh!  Sorry.  My bad.  I somehow missed that.